# UNQL with COUCHBASE

Tags: nosql, couchbase, unql

I am having a requirement that i want to inserted the record into COUCHBASE using UNQL,Can any one suggest me how to connect COUCHBASE using UNQL.

Regards
Pradeep

Answer (score 3):

Unql is an open project and a preview intended to help discussion on use cases for a query language with these newer databases.  It's not included in any release of Couchbase at the moment.

See [couchbase.com/develop](http://couchbase.com/develop) for info on how to insert data, etc.